# Expo: How can i save an image (from ImagePicker) into an album without duplicates?

Tags: react-native, expo

In my app a user can select a photo (from gallery or take one with the camera) and I want to save this photo into an album for my app.

I'm using expo 44.

I'm testing on android only. The version is 11.

My app.json has configured the proper permissions: "CAMERA", "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

This is a snippet of my code

```
// I pick the image from gallery or take a picture with the camera
const image = pickFromGallery ?
    await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({ mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images })
    :
    await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync()

if (!image.cancelled) {
    // I create the asset
    const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(image.uri)
    // I create a new album with the asset
    // The third argument is false because I want to move the image from the place that was created with "createAssetAsync" to the album
    // so there is no duplicates
    const album = await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync('myAppAlbum', asset, false)
    // I get the first album asset (just created so there is only one) in order to optain the image uri on the album
    const albumAssets = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
        album: album,
        first: 1
    })
    // I get the image uri in the album
    const imageUri = albumAssets.assets[0].uri
}
```

So whats happening is:

- I take the picture (or select it from gallery), this gives me an object with a uri that points to the image in memory
- I save the picture with "createAssetAsync" using this uri, this creates a file on /DCIM, and returns the asset ref
- Now I use the asset ref to create a new album, depending on the third parameter (true/false) it will behave like this:
- true: the asset is copied from /DCIM to the albums directory (in my case /Pictures/myAppAlbum). This is no good since it is creating duplicates of the image
- false: the asset is moved from /DCIM to the albums directory but it ask from permissions to modify the file. This is annoying since every time the user does this action he'll be asked for permission, and I'm unable to find what permission to request beforehand so the user only has to agree once.

[image: Picture of the requested permissions]

Is there a way to either:

- Save the image directly into the album aboiding the create of the file on /DCIM
- Ask the user for permissions only once instead of everytime

Comment: Did you ever resolved this? Did you requested file managing permissions ?

Comment: Any update to save picture from app cache to Album?